# IES-like lights in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, mathematics

I have been consistently trying and failing to recreate the techniques described in the links to create an IES like textured light effect with Cycles Spotlight lamps using a *Color Ramp* node.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?264052-IES-Like-Lights-in-Cycles-Architectural-Lighting or

http://www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?264052-IES-Like-Lights-in-Cycles-Architectural-Lighting/page2

According to the images you need the *Dot Product* between the *Normal* with *Incoming* connected to a *Color Ramp* node; however recreating the described node setup does not yield the same desired effect as shown bellow.

[image: Dot Product]

Using *Add* instead of *Dot Product* seems to show some effect, but it's not the expected result.

[image: Add]

Those images seem to be from older versions of Blender, using 2.65 and above I have never been able to achieve that effect.
Did something change internally that broke these techniques, or is there a new workflow to achieve the effect currently?

Did I miss something obvious? Hopefully someone with better math knowledge can solve this.

Comment: *Dot product* is the way. Couldn't be just a matter of setting the handles in a different positions? Without any kind of remap, values tend to be all in one place: maybe you missed them. Here's a screenshot of my testfile: http://imgur.com/8M1c3PR

Comment: The problem was not the handle position but your answer made me realize my mistake. What I did wrong was the light type, it must be an areal light, not a spot lamp. Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that [native IES support is in the works](http://adaptivesamples.com/2015/11/03/native-ies-support-on-its-way/) and there is already an [addon allowing it](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?276063-IES-Lamps-to-Cycles).

Comment: I knew about the addon, but never actually gave it a try,but with the upcoming patch it will hopefully become obsolete. I've also been following the patch for a while now, looking forward to those improvements as they will come in handy here is the link for the project https://developer.blender.org/D1543 and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did miss something obvious, thanks to Carlos comment I solved what was wrong with my scene.

The problem was not with the node setup itself, but with the object data. Light type must be an *Area Light*, not a *Spot Lamp*.

Using the correct area light type now yields expected results.