# How to access texture aspect ratio info (Cycles nodes)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm attempting to create a node tree that will set some scale values based on the aspect ratio of an image texture. I've been having no luck finding any solutions for accessioning this type of image texture info inside of a node tree.

The larger goal here is to implement this spot light projector effect with the correct aspect for any texture I assign without needing to manually set the scale values. [Spot light with square shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80001/spot-light-with-square-shape)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think image textures are aware of pixel aspect ratio, they just expect square pixels as far as I know. If they are then I know of no way to access that information from within a Cycles node tree, at least not without some scripting or python nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to shaders and didn't know that was the case. It's looking like I may be able to achieve my goal via scripting.