# How to project a video onto a mesh using UV Project modifier?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, camera

*I'd like to project a video onto a mesh but the projection is distorted when I use the UV Project modifier.*

What I basically would like to do is reconstructing a scene. I already have a camera track and prepared a model for the scene. The next step would be projecting a video as texture onto mesh. However, when I try to apply UV Project modifier set the aspect ratio, the texture comes out distorted. I tried to subdivide surface and did change the texture to some extent but no way to be correct.

[image: The mesh was line up in the viewer]
[image: Node Page]
[image: The UV Projection Setting]
[image: How the UV Projection turn out from camera view, extremely distorted]

**Q:** How to project a video onto a mesh using UV Project modifier?

Comment: Hi and welcome! UV project modifier works fine. In my experience you just have to add more geometry by using a subdivision modifier set to simple before adding the UV-project modifier. I'd suggest upload a simplified scene like a test grid with the same aspect ratio, preferably using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can have a look.

Comment: Your shader is not shadeless, the shadowing adds to the effect that the video looks distorted. There are ways to use spot lights as a projector (beamer), that might be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Related : Spot light with square shape https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80007/29586

Comment: OMG! Thanks Brockman, the subdiv modifier before UV Project WORK! Although I am still not sure what is the problem but it work!

Comment: Frederik, that is exactly what I was hoping to achieve. but not sure if the spotlight would project texture on the model that I would add to this scene later on.

Comment: Cool, issue is that project modifier needs a lot of geometry to project precisely. Do want it shadeless? @VemnLee

Comment: I am not sure if I need it shadeless. I was hoping to create some sort of distortion effect, like the floor is glitching out. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, basically I just try to light the scene again and apply the displacement. So I would still get the shadow from the displacement.