# How to custom shape the spotlight like oval and trapezoid in Cycles?

Tags: lighting

I am trying to change the shape of a spotlight in Blender.

From what I've tried so far Blender the spotlight only allows for a circular shape, and you can only adjust spot size and blend.

But I couldn't figure out a way to achieve the oval shape just yet.
What I want is the ability to squish and morph the shape of the spotlight.

How can I do this?

[image: Example of what I want to achieve]

Comment: Use IES files on area lights

Comment: What I've found to work around it is to add the texture in spotlight node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spot light with square shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80001/spot-light-with-square-shape)

Comment: Hi, @Lolabyte, welcome. Are you still looking for a more specific answer to this question? Will Blunder's link, above,  do? If not, please edit your question to explain why the linked answer doesn't work for you, to prevent it from being closed as a duplicate.