# Using IES light with iestocycles / rotation problem

Tags: add-on, import, lighting

I'm trying to use Ies lights in Blender using the addon which seems the only solution right now. It works OK with some problem. But I can't rotate the lamp on the Z axis at all. (I need a lamp which lights on a statue from the side, not a downlight.) I spent the whole afternoon but no luck till now. Did anyone face the same problem? 
(I would add a print screen but image uploading seems not working - not my day, I know...)
Thanks a lot, 
Attila

Comment: It is a known limitation of Cycles lamps at the moment, does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles Not a solution, but also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47756/ies-like-lights-in-cycles

Comment: Thaks a lot! You mean that the turning problem is a known issue or the lack of IES support?

Comment: The rotating problem is a known issue, I believe I've seen a patch somewhere that ameliorates the situation, though I don't know if it is planed for 2.79 or 2.8 series. There was also an old patch for native IES support in Cycles, but it never got integrated and I'm not sure it ever will.