# Radiate a pattern (png image) from a light

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I would like to radiate a pattern (png image) from a light source, but did not find what I'm missing here.
So at the final result, the object will be lighted with "black stripes"

Important for me to use the png as the filter for the radiate pattern.

Attached pattern and blend file
https://blend-exchange.com/b/pwxDdGpN

[image: pattern image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47756/ies-like-lights-in-cycles/47762#47762

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at other questions but they are not what I'm looking for.
Here as explained, I would like to have a png image as the filter for the radiate pattern but did not found how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here:

A) Your image is black on transparent, not black on white. so there is no data in the image that would emit light out of the box. Use it with a mix rgb node to fix that.

B) your image isnt optimal for your desired effect. my light source is litteraly a centimeter above the surface and the lines already start to blur. you won't see the lines as soon as the light source is a proper distance away from the bjects it's lighting.

Use actual objects to block the light instead.

[image]